# How can we send GCM messages in lots of 1000 to a database of, say, 10,000 registered users?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to send GCM messages using PHP and MySQL. Please help me out so that it can send GCM messages in lots of 1000 to a database of, say, 10,000 registered users.

Before crossing 1000 users, this script works fine; but after 1000 users, no one receives push.

Error I receive: `Number of messages on bulk (1082) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)`

```
//GCM Send Notification
function px_sendGCM($message, $type, $regid) {
global $wpdb;
$px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'gcm_users';
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
$apiKey = $options['api-key'];
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$result;
$id;

if($regid == 010) {
    $id = px_getIds();
}else {
    $id = $regid;
}

if($id == 010 && $id >= 1000){
    $newId = array_chunk($id, 1000);
    foreach ($newId as $inner_id) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $inner_id,
            'data' => array($type => $message) 
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        );

        $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'headers' => $headers,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'sslverify' => false,
            'body' => json_encode($fields) )
        );
    }
}else {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $id,
        'data' => array($type => $message)
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );

    $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => json_encode($fields))
    );

}

$msg = $result['body'];
$answer = json_decode($msg);
$cano = px_canonical($answer);
$suc = $answer->{'success'};
$fail = $answer->{'failure'};
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
if($options['debug'] != false){
    $inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>$msg</p></div>";
}else {
    $inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>".__('success:','px_gcm')." $suc  &nbsp;&nbsp;".__('fail:','px_gcm')." $fail </p></div>";
}
```

See [full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_VDsMSwf1ZBcHN0dDJ5a09mLUU/view).

Comment: checked the api's limits?

Comment: Can you post what is going wrong? It is difficult to understand what you are telling now.

Comment: i am not able to send push notification to more than 1000 users,

Comment: error i receive : Number of messages on bulk (1082) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)

Comment: well the error seems very clear to me

Comment: So how to fix it@Dagon

Answer (score 2):

```
//GCM Send Notification
function px_sendGCM($message, $type, $regid) {
global $wpdb;
$px_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'gcm_users';
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
$apiKey = $options['api-key'];
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$result;
$id;

if(sizeof($regid) == 010) {
$id = px_getIds(); //Can you post this function, what is this condition for?
}else {
$id = $regid;
}

if(sizeof($id) > 1000){ // the condition over here cannot be both equal to 10 and >= 1000
$newId = array_chunk($id, 1000);
foreach ($newId as $inner_id) {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $inner_id,
        'data' => array($type => $message) 
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );

    $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => json_encode($fields) )
    );
}
}else {
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $id,
    'data' => array($type => $message)
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);

$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => json_encode($fields))
    );

   }

$msg = $result['body'];
$answer = json_decode($msg);
$cano = px_canonical($answer);
$suc = $answer->{'success'};
$fail = $answer->{'failure'};
$options = get_option('gcm_setting');
if($options['debug'] != false){
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>$msg</p></div>";
}else {
$inf= "<div id='message' class='updated'><p><b>".__('Message    sent.','px_gcm')."</b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;($message)</i></p><p>".__('success:','px_gcm')." $suc  &nbsp;&nbsp;".__('fail:','px_gcm')." $fail </p></div>";
}
```

Comment: See the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_VDsMSwf1ZBcHN0dDJ5a09mLUU/view?usp=sharing: